# CSS bundling not working with MiniCssExtract plugin and css-loader (Webpack)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm working on a MERN project and I'm using sass for styling. To handle bundling of scss files I use [Node Sass Midleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-middleware) and everything works fine.

Now I want to use a react component ([react-multi-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel)) which requires me to import a stylesheet from the component:

```
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";
```

These are my scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server.js",
    "dev": "webpack -w -d --config=webpack.config.js"
  },
```

When I run `npm run dev` I don't get any errors and I get this output from Mini-Css-Extract plugin:

```
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!node_modules/react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
       6 modules
```

But when I run `npm run start` I get this error in `node_modules/react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css:1` :

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @font-face{font-family:"revicons";fallback:fallback;src:url("./revicons.woff") format('woff'),url("./revicons.ttf") format('ttf'),url("./revicons.eot") format('ttf')}.react-multi-carousel-list{display:flex;align-items:center;overflow:hidden;position:relative}.react-multi-carousel-track{list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;display:flex;flex-direction:row;position:relative;transform-style:preserve-3d;backface-visibility:hidden;will-change:transform,transition}.react-multiple-carousel__arrow{position:absolute;outline:0;transition:all .5s;border-radius:35px;z-index:1000;border:0;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);min-width:43px;min-height:43px;opacity:1;cursor:pointer}.react-multiple-carousel__arrow:hover{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8)}.react-multiple-carousel__arrow::before{font-size:20px;color:#fff;display:block;font-family:revicons;text-align:center;z-index:2;position:r

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/annacachadinaabello/Desktop/jornol/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is my webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!validator)/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
          loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      },
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
  noInfo: true,
  stats: 'minimal'
},
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Does anyone know why do I get this error?

Comment: Have you tried to use `raw-loader` instead of `css-loader`?

Comment: @AGrigorii If I use it wiht Mini-Css-Extract-Plugin I get this  [error](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/205) and if I try it without it I get the same error